# mplfinance support and resistance rays

Tags: python, charts, stock, mplfinance

I am trying to draw support and resistance on a chart but I only want it from certain dates to current. attaching pictures for reference of what I am aiming for and what I achieved. this is the code I used.

```
mf.plot(amzn, mav = (34, 50, 200), type = 'candle',hlines=dict(hlines=values,colors=color),
volume = True, figratio = (10,5),
style = 'binance', title = name,
tight_layout = True,)
```

Desired output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SakHf.png

actual output
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w99RN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hlines` kwarg, by definition, spans the entire plot from left to right.

What you need to do is use the `alines` kwarg instead.  See the [**using lines**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb) tutorial for more information on how to use `alines`.